# hyperlinks do not work in firefox but they work on chrome?

Tags: html, css, firefox

the hyperlinks in my page do not work on Firefox but they do work on chrome!

I have searched google and closest I could find to my problem was someone that added some css values to his tables but I do not have any css for my tables!

when i click on the buttons/hyperlinks on the page, nothing happens and it seems that the page expands as the scroll bar gets smaller!

I have removed the tables to see if this issue was created by the tables but it happened even without the tables on the page!

here is the link jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crf121359/RZhwK/

and here is a small portion of the code for the buttons (black band at the top) which i suspect to be the cause of the issue but I could be totally wrong.

HOME

```
<div id="btns2" style=
" border-right:dashed 1px #fff; width:150px; height:42px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; position:absolute; float:left; margin-left:174px;">
<span style="position:relative; top:10px; float:left; left:35px;"><a href=
"blog.php">BLOG</a></span>
</div>

<div id="btns2" style=
" border-right:dashed 1px #fff; width:220px; height:42px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; position:absolute; float:left; margin-left:348px;">
<span style="position:relative; top:10px; float:left; left:24px;"><a href=
"time-difference.php">TIME DIFFERENCE</a></span>
</div>
```

any help would be great.

EDIT: Just a quick note: I found out that the issue is from the CSS file as when i removed the css stylesheet from the HTML page, the hyperlinks work fine in firefox.

But I do not know what is causing the issue in the CSS file!

Comment: Probably you need a `/` at the start for the urls. e.g. `href="/blog.php"`

Comment: Little side note: The `<script>` attribute `language` is deprecated as seen in your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crf121359/RZhwK/)

Comment: What version of Firefox are you testing. Seems to work alright in FF23.

Comment: @ThomasCheney, it is firefox 23.0.1.

Comment: Use absolute path like `http://www.xxx.com/blog.php`

Comment: @ChinmaySahu, i tried that and didn't work.

Comment: Show your CSS and maybe someone can help

Comment: @Adsy, maybe you could view the jsfiddle?!

Comment: @SimonPresto thanks mate, I overlooked it

Comment: @Bondye, and why is that ?

Comment: its not the best written css I know but you still have not answered my question! why do i need to read a totally unrelated post ?

Comment: @Bondye, no you don't. because i posted the answer to my question.

Comment: @Bondye, I specifically said (YOU) do not need to answer as you seem to have a problem! reasons: 1- You posted a totally unrelated link in my question and demanded me to read it! 2- my code drove you crazy. 3- asked me why you need to read it which you don't and even if you did then you have wasted your time. and when i asked the question I didn't know the answer to it hence "asking the question".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "/" to the link `<a href="/blog.php">`

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to review some things in your code:

1. In jsfiddle I didn't noticed any html or body tag
2. You are using id selectors as multiple times like they are class selectors: take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp
3. why repeating multiple times the style inside the html code when you can write it once in the css?

Comment: 1- the jsfiddle will not allow you to post html and body tags. you dont need them when using jsfiddle. 2- i have reduced the errors on this page from 308 to 22. 3- as i said the issue is css related.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about jsfiddle. My hypothesis was that misusing the id could affect how different browser handles the page

Answer (score -1):

as i said the problem is was a css issue:

the issue is caused by this:

```
    #flagHolder a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
      margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#666;
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;
}
#flagHolder a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}


    #flagHolder2 a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
      margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#666;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
top:-266px;
left:250px;
}
#flagHolder2 a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}


    #flagHolder3 a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
      margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#666;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:0px;
margin-left:700px;
width:150px;
}
#flagHolder3 a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}

    #flagHolder4 a:link, a:active, a:visited{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
      margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#666;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:700px;
width:150px;
}
#flagHolder4 a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}
```